# Environmental variables are undefined in react

Tags: reactjs

Guys need your help.

I want to store variable in `.env` file and use it in `componentDidMount`. However, when I try and output it using `console.log()`, it is `undefined`.

I added a `.env` file in root directory.

```
REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID ='8eb5e613906409cd0202'
REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET ='6b06c1e6f682c2de048c47958f6af15911251d25'
```

[image: Screengrab of the code]

In the `console.log()` function, both `Id` and `secret` are `undefined`.

[edit: Here is the code]

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID)
  this.setState({ loading: true })
  axios.get(https://api.github.com/users?client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET})
    .then(res => this.setState({ users: res.data, loading: false }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here as text, instead of an image

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID)
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users?client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`)
      .then(res => this.setState({ users: res.data, loading: false }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))



  }

Comment: Put your .env.local to the project root (now it is in src folder).

Comment: REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID ='smt'

REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET ='smt'

Comment: What is project root, where it is

Comment: I've edited your question a bunch, and added the code you posted here to the question. :) Back on topic – I think what you're missing is the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package that will read your `.env` file into `process.env`, and allow you to use the variables during runtime. Go have a look at the link, there are clear instructions on how to add it to your project.

Comment: I have installed it

Comment: From the screenshot, it seems that your `.env.local` file is in your `./src` directory. It should be in the root (`./`) of the project. Try and move it up a directory, and rename it to `.env`.

Comment: i have moved it still undefined .Even restarted the server

Comment: The problem is that there is no dotenv package. I have  installed the wrong one npm install dotenv --save. Thank you very much, it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dotenv` library to manually load environment variables (since react fails to do so).

Install it using

```sh
npm i dotenv
```

In development, use it in the following manner:

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react'

import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' }) // path optional argument

// ...
```

Checkout more from npmjs.com [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Answer (score 1):

your `.env` file is not created properly and it is outside `src`
move it to `src` folder

Comment: I have moved but it still undefined

Comment: add this REACT_APP_MY_VAR=foo react-scripts start. add REACT_APP_ to every env file. const { REACT_APP_MY_VAR, REACT_APP_OTHER_VAR } = process.env;

Answer (score 0):

after creating .env file you need reset development server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).